# Selenium server -firefoxProfileTemplate can't work

Tags: testing, selenium

I want to start up Selenium server by specified firefox profile like blow command, but it didn't work well(can't open according to my specified profile), can somebody tell me if there were something wrong I used the command? Thanks!

ps: Windowns7 platform.

java -jar C:\Users\zhanjunw\Desktop\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -interactive -singleWindow -trustAllSSLCertificates -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\Users\zhanjunw\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\r91p21kg.seleniumProfile"

Comment: what error are you getting while trying to do this?

Comment: no any errors, just the firefox didn't start up by my specified profile, not the customized one. I changed the profile folder from appData\... to other one, and it works! seems we need to pay attention on the folder path. for your reference, thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 0):

The option firefoxProfileTemplate is not valid anymore.
Use webdriver.firefox.profile instead. Your command should be:

```
java -jar C:\Users\zhanjunw\Desktop\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -interactive -singleWindow -trustAllSSLCertificates -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=seleniumProfile
```

Note: 
Option webdriver.firefox.profile takes the NAME of the profile, not its location in the file system.
See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver